# scroll anchor show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

was working on a anchor point that triggers a divs visibility. There's no problems if I run it with Jquery 1.3.2 library but when I try with 1.7.1 it's not recognized. any ideas?

```
$(function() {
var a = function() {
var windowtop = $(window).scrollTop();
var d = $("#anchor").offset({scroll:false}).top;
var c= $("#flyout");
if (windowtop > d) {
  c.css({visibility:"visible"});
} else {
  if (windowtop <= d) {
    c.css({visibility:"hidden"});
  }
}
};
$(window).scroll(a);a()
});
});
```

Comment: What does your browser's error console say?

Comment: no errors show up in browser console. just doesn't get recognized so scrolling past anchor point doesn't trigger the visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d` seems to always return `undefined`.

I suspect your code breaks because of the `{scroll:false}` object your are passing as an argument to `offset()`. Removing it might solve your problem.

Check the [jQuery().offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) API;

`jQuery(elem).offset()`returns an object containing the element's top and left coordinates. Can be used as `jQuery(elem).offset().top;`.

`jQuery(elem).offset({top:20, left:20});` sets the new top and left coordinates for the element.